# Can I share a single file between containers in a pod?

Tags: kubernetes

My pod has two containers - a primary container, and a sidecar container that monitors the `/var/run/utmp` file in the primary container and takes action when it changes. I'm trying to figure out how to make this file visible in the sidecar container.

[This page](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/communicate-containers-same-pod-shared-volume/) describes how to use an `emptyDir` volume to share directories between containers in a pod. However, this only seems to work for directories, not single files. I also can't use this strategy to share the entire `/var/run/` directory in the primary container, since mounting a volume there erases the contents of the directory, which the container needs to run.

I tried to work around this by creating a symlink to `utmp` in another directory and mounting that directory, but it doesn't look like symlinks in volumes are resolved in the way they would need to be for this to work.

Is there any way I can make one file in a container visible to other containers in the same pod? The manifest I'm experimenting with looks like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: utmp-demo

spec:
  restartPolicy: Never

  containers:
  - name: main
    image: debian
    command: ["/bin/bash"]
    args: ["-c", "sleep infinity"]
    volumeMounts:
    - name: main-run
      mountPath: /var/run  # or /var/run/utmp, which crashes

  - name: helper
    image: debian
    command: ["/bin/bash"]
    args: ["-c", "sleep infinity"]
    volumeMounts:
    - name: main-run
      mountPath: /tmp/main-run

  volumes:
  - name: main-run
    emptyDir: {}
```

Comment: Not sure if subPath could work here, but it might be worth trying.[Here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/41638) is an example. But I would try including the file name with the path, similar to how you would include only one file of a configMap.

Comment: Doesn't seem to help, even with subPath the rest of the directory seems to get cleared out.

Comment: What about simply creating /var/run/utmp file with the same permissions as the original one when main container starts? I think it is already an empty file in the beginning (without mounting any volume).

Comment: If you need the original content of /var/run, you can access masked files with "mkdir /somedir; mount -o bind / /somedir; cp -r /somedir/var/run/* /var/run; umount /somedir". Your container need to be privileged for this to work, otherwise mount command throws permission denied.

Answer (score 1):

If you can move the file to be shared in an empty subfolder this could be a simple solution.

For example, move your file to /var/run/utmp/utmp and share /var/run/utmp folder with an emptydir.

Comment: Unfortunately this won't work in my case since the location of /var/run/utmp is defined by Linux and can't be moved.